# Ninject does not resolve my registered services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have ASP.NET Mvc application and I integrated Ninject as I installed [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/) nuget package which updated my code. I added a NinjectWebCommon class to the App_Start folder of my solution. What I did was to register some of my interfaces and their implementations:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  kernel.Bind<ITokenManager>().To<TokenManager>();
}
```

The problem is that when I try to resolve an instance of this interface:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

var tokenManager = kernel.Get<ITokenManager>();
```

I get an error. What it says is:

> Error activating ITokenManager No matching bindings are available, and
>   the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:  1) Request for
>   ITokenManager
>
> Suggestions:  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for
>   ITokenManager.  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that
>   the module has been loaded into the kernel.  3) Ensure you have not
>   accidentally created more than one kernel.  4) If you are using
>   constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the
>   constructors parameter name.  5) If you are using automatic module
>   loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.

I don't really understand it as all of the tutorials explain the configuration in the exact same way as I did it.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have created a new kernel instance:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
```

Here you specify that this kernel instance should look for **modules** in the current assembly:

```
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

In Ninject terms, a *module* is a class that implements the `NinjectModule` class. For example a class like this one that you could add to your current assembly:

```
public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<ITokenManager>().To<TokenManager>();
    }
}
```

In your question you just seem to have showed some `RegisterServices` method which is quite unclear by whom it is being called and under what circumstances but you cannot possibly expect that this method would get used somehow by your newly instantiated kernel.

You are probably confused because this `RegisterServices` method is called by an assembly attribute at application startup, but remember that this method operates on a quite different instance of the `kernel` parameter. In your case you have a completely different instance that you created manually somewhere in your code. So if you expect to be able to properly resolve dependencies from a kernel please make sure that those dependencies are registered in the **same** kernel instance form which you are expecting to resolve them.

Comment: So, in order to register my mappings, I need to have it on both places - Custom ninject module and the Common class that is automatically  generated in App_Start?

Comment: Yes, but it is unclear why you need a separate `kernel` instance in the first place. Normally you should have a single dependency injection kernel instance for your entire application and register all dependencies inside this kernel. Why are you manually creating a new instance of a kernel?

Comment: I am just trying to resolve in instance out of an interface. Usually this interface is passed to a constructor of something but in my case I need it at a place where no explicit constructor is available. It is the Startup.cs class of the MVC application.

Comment: To resolve an instance out of an interface you need to register it somewhere - in a dependency injection container. Ninject is one such container and the `kernel` is its representation. So as I already stated in my answer, make sure that you register the instance inside the same kernel instance from which you are expecting to resolve it.

Comment: Well, I don't really know what kernel is and how it works. I know the basics of dependency injection and why we use it. But I don't really understand what you're trying to tell me in order to improve my code.

Comment: What I am trying to tell you to improve your code is that in an ASP.NET MVC application you should not be writing `var kernel = new StandardKernel();`. This code is already there when you installed the Ninject NuGet. All you need to do is to register your instances inside the `RegisterServices` method (as you already did) and then they will be automatically injected inside your ASP.NET MVC controller constructors. Everything will be wired automatically in this case and you should never need to write `kernel.Get<ITokenManager>()` code. Just have a controller take `ITokenManager` as parameter.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to tell you. I usually put the interfaces in my class constructor but this time there was no explicit one so I had to reach the container somehow. That is why I made an instance of the standart kernel.

Comment: You should not be *reaching* your container. The whole point is that your classes must have constructors taking interfaces and the container will **inject** the proper implementations into those constructors. That's how DI works. If you do not have constructors then you are no longer using any Inversion Of Control and you are basically using the Service Locator Pattern which is tightly coupling your code with the DI container itself. If you need to do this for some reason then just use the same kernel variable in which your dependencies were registered. Make it public static for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143607/discussion-between-user2128702-and-darin-dimitrov).